# Is there a way to add custom audit logs for encryption/decryption operations of keys save in key vault?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

I am trying to set up a service in which we will use Customer Managed Encryption Keys to encrypt/decrypt data, but with each opeation we want to send a custom header in which it specifies the reason of the operation. AWS has this custom audit log funcitonality and I was wondering if there is a way to do that in azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, Azure regrettably doesn't support custom audit logs encryption/decryption operations to send a custom header indicating the specific purpose of the operation.